Send SNMP logs to AWS S3
Is it possible for AWS S3 to accept logs from 3rd party applications (non-AWS service)?
I was tasked to configure our Wi-fi controller to send SNMP logs to AWS S3 storage and those logs are being read by a business analytics software (provided by a 3rd-party vendor)
I asked the 3rd-party vendor to send me the SNMP details of their application such as community name, IP/FQDN using port 161/162 so I can input the destination address in our Wifi-Controller.
But Instead, I was given a URL link of an S3 using port 443.
I have no idea how AWS S3 works and unsure whether the details provided is sufficient enough to establish connection.

S3 has a published API, anything that uses that API can call it. That application needs permissions to talk to the S3 bucket you need to write to. You'd need to provide more details to get a more useful answer.
